# Create Joomla admin fields dynamically with javascript

Tags: joomla3.0

I'd like to create an admin form in Joomla where the presence and quantity of some elements are dependent on the options selected for other elements.

For example if you have two calendar elements to allow the selection of a start and end date, then based on the number of days selected I'd like the form to dynamically create that number of text fields (one for each day).

I've done this before in Joomla 1.5, but I had to write all the PHP and JS from scratch. This time I'd like the Joomla form API to do some of the heavy lifting if that is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Joomla form field type ["repeatable"](https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type) answers my question. However it seems too buggy to use in production code at the moment.